# How to modify androidmanifest.xml to use a class that extends ListActivity?

Tags: android

I have two classes one that extends Activity and inside that class file I called another intent which class extends ListActivity. How do I change the androidmanifest.xml file to load that two activities? I should say that I declared both of the activities in androidmanifest.xml file as

```
<activity android:name="NoteActivity"></activity>
<activity android:name="AddNote"></activity>
```

the **NoteActivity** extends `Activity` and the **AddNote** extends `ListActivity`; when I run it it doesn't run and said "stopped" unfortunately.

Comment: there is no change in manifest file with activity and list activity your problem should be something else post your log

Comment: please post the logcat and codesnippet if you can

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your newly created activities in manifest too. So simply update your **AndroidManifest.xml** at least as minimum as below:

```
<activity android:name=".NoteActivity" android:label="Activity1" />

<activity android:name=".AddNote" android:label="Activity2" />
```

*It is assumed that your activity files are placed in root of your package as defined in **manifest** and make sure the class names are correctly depicted in the xml above.

**Note:** Make sure your activity starts with a **dot** (.) symbol too.

Comment: Should I need to provide the android::label for those activities i mean is it must??

Comment: No, its optional. However, i provided it so you may know by title when a second activity is launched :)

Comment: also notice that i'm writing an activity with a **dot** sign in manifest

Comment: @TanveerAhmed if you are using eclipse open the manifest click applications tab->in application node -> click add ->select activity and add from the listed stuff so you dont have the hazle